# Blog - comment count on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, comments, blogs

Am trying to display a 'total comments' number (i.e.7) count beside the article on the index page and not on the article page. Would like to use a ruby method for this as its probably the most straight forward...?

views/articles/_article.html.erb

```
<div class="article_header">
<b>Title: </b> <%= truncate(article.title, :length => 50) %> 
by <%= article.user.username %> on <%= article.created_at.strftime("%d %B, %Y") %> 
<b>Detail:</b> <%= truncate(article.body, :length => 225) %>
</div>
<br />
<%= blog.comments.count %>


<%= link_to 'Read', article %>
 <% if can? :update, article %>
 | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> |      

<% end %>
```

Comment: Surely you do it exactly the same way as you would anywhere else?

Comment: You mean `<%= blog.comments.count %>`?

Comment: @mischa I tried this code on the index.html.erb page but its not right?! Shouldn't it query the db for the answer - not sure what the 'blog' object relates to?

Comment: @ubique, since you didn't include code before I was guessing the name of your object was `blog`, but apparently it is `article`. Try `article.comments.count`. If this doesn't work show us how you set up associations in your models.

Comment: @mischa I added some code to clarify the question batter. I have used your suggestion article.comments.count and seems to be working fine. Is this method expensive in resources?

Comment: Unless you have a huge number of comments and haven't set up indexes correctly, it shouldn't be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a variable when you call your partial:

```
= render "article", :display_count => true
```

Then in your partial:

```
<% display_count ||= false %>
<%= display_count ? blog.comments.count : '' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
<td><%= link_to "Comment count = #{article.comments.count}", article_path(article) %>
```

This will simply add another column to the output on your index page. It doesn't have to be linked if you simply want to display the count:

```
<td><%= "Comment count = #{article.comments.count}" %>
```